# Is there a difference between Ruby's Hash "value?" and "has_value?"

Tags: ruby

I'm looking at `Hash` docs for [`has_value?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html#method-i-has_value-3F) and [`value?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html#method-i-value-3F).  However the link for `value?` leads to duplicate information about `has_value?`.

`value?` seems to work identically to `has_value?` (Ruby 3.02).

Does this mean `value?` is becoming deprecated or is this a documentation error?

Comment: It's just an `alias`, no documentation error and probably won't become deprecated.

Comment: Ruby has quite a lot of methods like this, where there’s some identical or near-identical ways to do something. Just pick the one you find easiest to use.

Comment: `key?` even has 3 aliases: `has_key?`, `include?` and `member?`

Comment: @Stefan it is interesting that the docs say *"Methods has_key?, key?, and member? are aliases for #include?."* but the source code suggests that it should be *"Methods include?, key?, and member? are aliases for #has_key?."* since the C method is called `rb_hash_has_key`

Comment: @engineersmnky good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if they are identical by comparing their method objects:

```
Hash.instance_method(:value?) == Hash.instance_method(:has_value?)
#=> true
```

[`UnboundMethod#==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/UnboundMethod.html#3D-3D-method) returns `true` if the methods refer to the same implementation.

---

> Does this mean value? is becoming deprecated or is this a documentation error?

It seems to be a documentation error. The docs from the official website are more explicit regarding the alias:

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_value-3F

> #### `has_value?(value) → true or false`
>
> Returns `true` if `value` is a value in `self`, otherwise `false`.
>
> *Also aliased as: `value?`*

However, the entry for `value?` doesn't have a heading: (the bold `value?(value) → true or false` part is missing)

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-value-3F

> Returns `true` if `value` is a value in `self`, otherwise `false`.
>
> *Alias for: `has_value?`*